# Finding two non-subsequent elements in array which sum is maximal - interview question

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, max

The question is similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209524/finding-two-non-subsequent-elements-in-array-which-sum-is-minimal), besides:

1. We are looking for the maximum.
2. The answer can contain the first or last element of the array (but not both - because we consider them as adjacent).

My attempt:

I think of using the same idea of RomCoo in the link above, but adjust it to this problem:

1. Find the largest number.
2. Find the second largest that is not a neighbour of the first. Then build the sum.
3. Calculate the sum of both neighbours of the first number. Check if its larger then the first sum.
   If not: take the first sum, otherwise take the second one.

I believe that the pairs on steps (2) and (3) are the only ones who can make the largest sum, but I can't formally prove it.
If this correct how can you formally prove it?
And if not, how do you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume we have two numbers `A` and `B` that make up a larger sum. Either `A` or `B` (or both) must not be directly adjacent to the largest number, because otherwise they fall into (3). Lets take this to be `A`, without loss of generality. Since `A` is not adjacent to our largest number, then `B` could be safely replaced by our largest number if its not already, resulting in a greater overall sum. Therefore, to be maximal, `B` must equal our largest number. By the same logic, if there existed a larger value than `A` not adjacent to our largest number, then this sum would not be maximal either, so `A` must be the second largest number. This means `A` and `B` would fall into (2). So, (2) and (3) are our only valid solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the question is "somewhat" similar to 1031 LeetCode question, which you can see it in [this link](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-sum-of-two-non-overlapping-subarrays/):

#### Python

```py
class Solution:
    def maxSumTwoNoOverlap(self, nums, l, m):
        for index in range(1, len(nums)):
            nums[index] += nums[index - 1]
        largest = nums[l + m - 1]
        l_max, m_max = nums[l - 1], nums[m - 1]
        for index in range(l + m, len(nums)):
            l_max = max(l_max, nums[index - m] - nums[index - l - m])
            m_max = max(m_max, nums[index - l] - nums[index - l - m])
            largest = max(largest, l_max + nums[index] - nums[index - m], m_max + nums[index] - nums[index - l])

        return largest
```

#### Java

```java
class Solution {
    public int maxSumTwoNoOverlap(int[] nums, int l, int m) {
        for (int index = 1; index < nums.length; index++)
            nums[index] += nums[index - 1];

        int largest = nums[l + m - 1];
        int lMax = nums[l - 1];
        int mMax = nums[m - 1];

        for (int index = l + m; index < nums.length; index++) {
            lMax = Math.max(lMax, nums[index - m] - nums[index - l - m]);
            mMax = Math.max(mMax, nums[index - l] - nums[index - l - m]);
            largest = Math.max(largest, Math.max(lMax + nums[index] - nums[index - m], mMax + nums[index] - nums[index - l]));
        }

        return largest;
    }
}
```

For your question, you are gonna have to keep a minimum distance of 2 as you scan your array so that the neighboring section would be addressed. For instance, you maximize for `index` and `index + 2` as you scan or `index - 2` and `index`.

#### Reference

[Here is lee215's answer in Java/Python/C++](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-sum-of-two-non-overlapping-subarrays/discuss/278251/JavaC%2B%2BPython-O(N)Time-O(1)-Space)